# How to find the maximum value of n that satisfies the sum of a sequence of numbers?

Tags: differential-equations

Given the sequence a[n], the sum of the first n terms in the sequence is s[n],

where n is a positive integer.

When n is at [2^(k-1), 2^k), then a[n_]=2^k, and k is a positive integer,

find the maximum value of the positive integer n that holds s[n]<2022

```
a[n_] = If[{2^(k - 1) <= n < 2^k, k \[Element] PositiveIntegers}, 2^k]
```

I tried it myself, but there was a problem with the general formula

Comment: The tag "differential-equations" seems quite a stretch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear[a, s]
a[n_Integer] := Module[
  {k},
  k = Floor[Log[2, n] + 1];
  2^k]
s[n_Integer] := Sum[a[i], {i, 1, n}]

NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, s[#] < 2022 &] - 1
(* 51 *) 

s[51]
(* 1962 *)
s[52]
(* 2026 *)
```

---

**EDIT**:

`a[i]`s are repeatedly computed with the above implementation with `Sum` and `NestWhile`, e.g., in testing `s[4]<2022` after testing `s[3]<2022`, all the `a[i]`s except `a[4]` are recomputed.

Note that `s[n] = s[n-1] + a[n]`, so we may just:

```
First[NestWhile[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] + a[#[[1]] + 1]} &, {1, 
    a[1]}, #[[2]] < 2022 &]] - 1

(* 51 *)
```

Another way, we may use the memoization, such as [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html.en?source=footer) and [that by szhorvat](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/memoization-in-mathematica.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid iterating it can be done formulaically. We use a function to compute the sum for powers of 2 and another to give the `n` that gets to such a power.

```
sum1[k_] = Sum[2^n*2^(n - 1), {n, k}];
sum2[k_] = Sum[2^(n - 1), {n, k}];
```

We also need a function to invert the first one above and extract the `Floor`.

```
lowExponent[n_] := Floor[First[NSolveValues[sum1[k] == n && k > 1, k]]]
```

Now we can use these and do a quick quotient to see how far we have to go at the next level.

```
maxUnder[n_] := With[{lowE = lowExponent[n]},
  sum2[lowE] + Floor[(n - sum1[lowE])/2^(lowE + 1)]]
```

Example:

```
maxUnder[2022]

(* Out[331]= 51 *)
```

I apologize for the uninspired function names and the even less inspired explanation. Maybe it's just not my day for clarity.

On the plus side, this method is pretty fast.

```
maxUnder[2022^202] // Timing

(* Out[361]= {0.003634, \
8848412971663091221718486019366725826876038928718791960496214510185100\
2756313339789362784310738600294437488431058648509122782268195260731096\
2698748759207703006494701238381383269788249231560021717717656442703134\
6136171077852358900869531539535081576202445462527581584040000708152338\
085124485774977647714843738024701074430022309498144970} *)
```

(Better to be fast than pretty, as they say in track.)